# Creating BaseDAO for Each Dao class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I created a spring application where i decided to add a BaseDAO to eliminate redundant create,
update,delete,findByid,and findAll methods for every dao. So i created a baseDao and every dao should extend this BaseDAO.

### BaseDaoImpl

```
public class BaseDAOImpl implements BaseDAO{

    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    @Override
    public void create(ModelBase modelBase) {

         Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
         session.persist(modelBase);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ModelBase modelBase) {

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
         session.update(modelBase);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection findAll(Class aClass) {

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Collection  modelCols = session.createQuery("from "+aClass.getSimpleName()).list();
        return modelCols;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelBase findById(Class aClass, Integer id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();     
        ModelBase modelBase = (ModelBase) session.load(aClass, new Integer(id));
        return modelBase;
    }



}
```

Then i extends this Dao to each DAO

### EmployeeDAOImp

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl extends BaseDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO{

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }
}
```

I created a BaseService like this. But when i try to access BaseDAO methods from EmployeeDAO it returns null pointer exception.
Why this happen. I dont want to use genericDAO from google. Because we should create DAOs
for each model. I want to eliminate this. So I follow this method.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace for your null pointer exception, it will describe accurately what is failing. The obvious failing in your code is that you are shadowing the definition of SessionFactory. Deleting the posted body in EmployeeDAOImpl will probably fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are overriding `setSessionFactory` from base class for no reason, its already available with extending class `EmployeeDAOImpl` , either remove it or try below:

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl extends BaseDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO{

   //this reference should be from base class,
   // the extending class ref is hiding base ref.
  //  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
      super.setSessionFactory(sf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you though about Spring Data project & Spring Data JPA in particular?

This would save you lots of time, since you would no longer need to write your DAO / Repositories from scratch, all you need to do is enable Spring Data JPA, and add needed interfaces. It should save you tons of time.

- http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/
- http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ - Sample project

Comment: I agree. Spring Data simplifies the model layer and reduces boiler-plate code of common DAO layer. Good documentation and better examples. In my case, I am working with JPA+Hibernate with a totally free XML configuration

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work (note the use of constructor rather than setter injection). In the BaseDAO:

```
public class BaseDAOImpl implements BaseDAO {

  private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public BaseDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

Then in the Employee DAO:

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl extends BaseDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

  @Inject
  public EmployeeDAOImpl (SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super(sessionFactory);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create generic dao.

```
@Repository("genericDao")
public class GenericDaoImpl<T,PK extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, PK> {

    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    public T create(T t) {
       this.entityManager.persist(t);
       return t;
    }

    public T read(PK id,Class<T> c) {
       return (T)this.entityManager.find(c, id);
    }

    public T update(T t) {
       return this.entityManager.merge(t);
    }

    public void delete(T t) {
        t = this.entityManager.merge(t);
       this.entityManager.remove(t);
    }

    public List<T> getAll(Class<T> c){
        return this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT o FROM "+ c.getName() +" o").getResultList();
    }
  }
```

### UPDATED

You can use as following, TimeRange is a pojo class in the following example. If you do not want a service layer. You can use timeRangeDao in controller.

```
@Service("timeRangeService")
public class TimeRangeServiceImpl implements TimeRangeService{
    @Autowired
    GenericDao<TimeRange,Long> timeRangeDao;

    public List<TimeRange> getAllTimeRanges(){
            return timeRangeDao.getAll(TimeRange.class);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void createTimeRange(TimeRange c) {
            timeRangeDao.create(c);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(TimeRange p) {
            timeRangeDao.update(p);
    }

    @Transactional
    public TimeRange getTimeRange(long id) {
            return timeRangeDao.read(id, TimeRange.class);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(long id) {
            TimeRange timeRange = new TimeRange();
            timeRange.setId(id);
            timeRangeDao.delete(timeRange);
    }

 }
```

Comment: But using this generic DAo i have to create dao for every model. I have more than 100 model class

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If you use generic dao. You can use GenericDao<TimeRange,Long> timeRangeDao; Just supply the class and you will be fine.

Comment: How could i use it?could you please explain