# How to pass wildcard to Class<T> in persistance api?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to create an abstract class, to avoid bloating code for each DAO class.

```java
public abstract GenericDAO<T> {
    public Optional<T> fetch(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(T, id)
    }
}
```

I have tried the previous, but neither `T` nor `T.class` works.
My goal is to simply have other DAOs extend this class.

How do i make this work? As in, how do i pass the wildcard as parameter to `.find`?

Edit:

To better illustrate.

I have DAO for each entity. Lets say `ADao`, `BDao`. The only difference between `ADao` and `BDao` is a the moment the fact, that they each accept and return different type. The JPA, however, doesn't care. Thus I want to create `AbstractDao<T>`, and have the children be `ADao<EntityA>` and `BDao<EntityB>`.

Thus, `ADao` nor `BDao` will include the repeated code, but each will work on the specific entity classes `EntityA` and `EntityB` (respectively).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Added the explicit wording.

Comment: Do the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242839/creating-basedao-for-each-dao-class help you?

Comment: That's contradictory to what i am trying to do. If the concrete DAO uses generic types, there is no point in having the conrete DAOs altogether.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for? Still not sure about your goal.

```
abstract class GenericDAO<T> {

    public abstract Optional<T> fetch(Long id);
}

class DaoChild extends GenericDAO<YourClass>{

   @Override
   public Optional<YourClass> fetch(Long id) {
      return entityManager.find(YourClass.class,id);
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. EntityManager class takes class as the first argument. There is no one argument version.

Comment: Maybe you can post your entire code, edited adding the class as 1st parameter

Comment: Yeah, once again, all you did was add an interface. This doesn't solve code redundancy. Each different DAO child has to implement the same code, only difference being `YourClass.class`

Comment: There you go then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-do-i-get-a-class-instance-of-generic-type-t